# How can I make the camera taller in the Blender Game engine?

Tags: game-engine, camera

I was making a first person game in Blender and I wanted my character to be taller, at the moment the character is just a camera set to character physics. I cannot scale each individual factor [x, y, z] on their own and making it bigger on all factors makes it impossible to control, is there anyway to fix this and make my camera taller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By making your camera taller do you mean to change the resolution? Your character and your camera should never be the same object. Make a cube (this will be your character), and parent the camera to it. The camera should be set to no collision and the box to dynamic. You can change the shape of the cube if you want the character to be taller. Or if you just want the camera to be higher up you could just move it up in the Z-axis.

If you are meaning resolution then you can simply adjust it in the Output tab under dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**Size and Focal Length**

Do you mean the size and focal length?

[image]

If yes just make the focal length smaller number and\or make the size bigger number.
What is do? Is make the fov of view camera big.

**Resolution**

Do you mean make the camera tall by the height or width and it is not changing by the x,y,z axis scale?
It is easy, you want to change the *Embedded Player Resolution*:

[image]

Now change that x\y and you will be see the camera is taller!

Example:
Now I have the Resolution like this:

[image]

I will see this:

[image]

It was like this:

[image]

so now try what you need and see.

Comment: try what you need and see!